# .java.lang.NullPointerException ...for CaptureScreenshots . even correct path provided

Tags: selenium

This is Exception i got for  takeScreenshot ..for correct path

I dont understand route cause even knowing  nullpointerexception 
For Screenshots i have provided correct screenshots
please help me for this

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.testing.core.ddf.base.BaseTest.takeScreenshot(BaseTest.java:167)
at com.testing.core.ddf.testcases.DummyTestB.TestB(DummyTestB.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
-----------------------------------------------
public void takeScreenshot()
{
    Date  d =new Date();
    //String screenshotFile  = d.toString().replace(":", "_").replace(" ", "_")+".png";
    String screenshotFile  = d.toString().replace(":", "_").replace(" ", "_")+".png";
    File scrFile  =((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try 
    {
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Screenshots\\"+screenshotFile));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }

    //test.log(LogStatus.INFO,"Screenshot-> "+ test.addScreenCapture("E:\\selenium_practice\\Maven_Workspace\\Data_Driven_core_Framework\\Screenshots"+screenshotFile));
```

Line 167.

```
test.log(LogStatus.INFO,"Screenshots -> "+test.addScreenCapture(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//Screenshots//"+screenshotFile));
}
```

---

DummyTestB .java

```
public class DummyTestB extends BaseTest {
ExtentReports rep  =ExtentManager.getInstance();
ExtentTest test ;

@Test
public void TestB() throws IOException
{

    test = rep.startTest("DummmyTestB");
    test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Starting the DummyTest");

    OpenBrowser("Mozilla");
    test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Opened the Browser");
    //driver.System.out.println("This is Test B1");
    Navigate("FBURL");
    test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Navigated to URL");
    type("FBUser_id","FB_username");
    test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Entered username");
    type("FBPass_id","FB_password");
    test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Entered Password");
    Click("Login_Button_Xpath");
    test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "clicked to Login");
    test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test Case B Pass");
    //
Line no 39  takeScreenshot();
}
```

Comment: what is there on line `BaseTest.java:167` ?

Comment: BaseTest.java:167     i.e. at line 167 there is below code                                                                                      test.log(LogStatus.INFO,"Screenshots -> "+test.addScreenCapture(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//Screenshots//"+screenshotFile));

Comment: at line 39 takeScreenshot();.......................................................................................at com.testing.core.ddf.testcases.DummyTestB.TestB(DummyTestB.java:39

Comment: Please post the full file or file with line numbers so one can make out the exact exception location

Comment: I have updated  the post along with line number

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `test.log(LogStatus.INFO,"Screenshots -> "+test.addScreenCapture(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//Screenshots//"+screenshotFile));` and inspect which value is coming as null. It could be `test` or `System.getProperty("user.dir")` or `screenshotFile`

Comment: during debugging  when point come at  test.log(LogStatus.INFO,"Screenshots -> "+test.addScreenCapture(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//Screenshots//"+screenshotFile));                                                              page redirect to Invocation TargetException                                      public InvocationTargetException(Throwable target) {
        super((Throwable)null);  // Disallow initCause
        this.target = target;

Comment: <init>() threw NullPointerException  (id=1082)                                                           
this InvocationTargetException  (id=1084) 
arg0 NullPointerException  (id=1082)

Comment: It's Resolved .. I added in BaseTest.java                                                public ExtentTest test =rep.startTest("BaseTest"); and Runned Successfully...Thanks for Suggestion